# How can I simulate 10s or 100s of clicks on my webpage

Tags: javascript, html, testing, web-applications

I have an intermittent bug on a webpage and I need to keep clicking a link that opens a popup then close the popup and click the link again. I need to do this many times. How can I simulate this so its done automatically while I watch?

Answer (score 2):

I would use any testing framework for this, e.g. [Selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/), record a macro of actions needed and updated the code if necessary for this special purpose...

Answer (score 2):

you could use [selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/), particularly the [selenium IDE](http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-ide/1.10.0/selenium-ide-1.10.0.xpi).

Answer (score 0):

In firefox you have a plugin "DejaCLick"
If you want to see you cursor on screen clicking and closing the popup hundreds of times, this is a good way.

https://addons.mozilla.org/nl/firefox/addon/dejaclick/

DejaClick records your mousemovements and clicks and is able to repeat that as many times you like!

Answer (score -1):

you can simulate a click in following way:

```
<a id="a" href="javascript:;" onclick="alert(1)" >sometext</a>
<script>
for(var i=0;i<100;i++){
  document.getElementById("a").click();
}
</script>
```